# Injecting services in Redux Epic Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, redux, redux-observable

I am using "redux-observable" for Redux capablities in AngularJS v1.6. 
Following code is for an Epic

```
export const getAllBidsAPI : any = (action$: ActionsObservable<any>, store: any, { customerService = CustomerService }) =>
      action$.ofType(GET_ALL_BID)
        .mergeMap((action : any) =>
          Observable.fromPromise(customerService.getCustomers())
            .map((res: any) => ({type : GET_ALL_BID_SUCCESS , payload : res.data.bid}))
        );
```

Here **CustomerService is not recognized.** I guess, its not injected.

```
const rootEpic = combineEpics(
  getAllBidsAPI
);

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  bidReducer
});

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic, {
    dependencies : {CustomerService} 
});

export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware)
);
```

This is where we add CustomerService as dependency in Epic. But, I get error.

> Cannot read property 'getCustomers' of undefined

Comment: how do you resolve that dependency?

Comment: @Hitmands what do exactly mean by resolving dependency?

Comment: AngularJS (1.*) has `$injector` Object, that means you need to register dependencies and use them only where allowed by the framework (inside components, services, controllers, etc...). So, how do you resolve `customerService` lowercase? you made: `dependencies : {CustomerService} ` in uppercase...

Comment: So where should I add $injector object? I'm really confused.

Comment: you should know `angularjs`, otherwise try to have a look here: https://github.com/marceloemanoel/redux-angularjs-example

Comment: @Hitmands Great example, but they never injected any service into the epic function. How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for a dependency being `undefined` in redux-observable is that it is actually provided as `undefined`; usually because the import/require is incorrect. Double check that you are importing `CustomerService` correctly, as well as pause your debugger in the file where you pass it to `createEpicMiddleware` to confirm that it is (or is not) `undefined`.

The other thing I've seen is they were using an old version of redux-observable that did not yet support the dependency injection. **However** I'm pretty confident it's the first suggestion above because redux-observable does not provide anything as the third argument to your epic *by default*. So in your case, if redux-observable was to blame, you would actually get `Cannot read property 'customerService' of undefined` because the third argument would be nothing, instead it's the object you provided.

Comment: Hey ANKIT. Was that the issue?